# Check if given string matches one of set of prefixes, effectively

Tags: perl, match, matching

What algorithm to use to check if a given string matches one of set of prefixes, and which prefix from that set?

Other variation: given path and a set of directories, how to check if path is in one of set of directories (assuming that there are no symbolic links, or they do not matter)?

I'm interested in description or name of algorithm, or Perl module which solves this (or can be used to solve this).

**Edit**
Bonus points for solution which allow to effectively find *'is prefix of'* relation between set of strings (set of directories)

For example, given set of directories: `foo, foo/bar, foo/baz, quux, baz/quux, baz/quux/plugh` the algorithm is to find that `foo` is prefix of `foo/bar` and `foo/baz`, and that `baz/quux` is prefix of `baz/quux/plugh`... hopefully without O(n^2) time.

Comment: +1 just for the simple fact that you don't want to reinvent the wheel if you don't have to!

Comment: I think my examples now reflect your edit, if not then please further explain

Comment: my examples can certainly be extended to loop over inputs and find output, but I think they will be O(n^2) up to savings by short-circuiting. Perhaps someone more clever than I will have some more efficient way of doing this. I imagine its going to require something like joining and regexing the joined sets; as long as you have two lists that need to be compared I think it will have to be O(n^2) as far as I can understand

Comment: see my edit on Aho-Corasick and Trie matching, hope you find something in that or that someone else has more. We are at my limit of knowledge, Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient way to do this would be using a Trie:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

There is a package for it on CPAN:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Tree::Trie

(never used that package myself though)

You need to consider your what operations need to be the most efficient. The lookup is very cheap in a Trie, but if you only build the trie for one lookup, it might not be the fastest way...

Answer (score 1):

You pose an interesting question, but as I went out to look for such a thing (in `List::MoreUtils` for example), I kept coming back to, how is this any different than a `grep`. So here it is, my basic implementation based on `grep`. If you don't mind searching the whole list, or want all the matches here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @prefixes = qw/ pre1 pre2 pre3 /;

my $test = 'pre1fixed';
my @found = grep { $test =~ /^$_/ } @prefixes;

print "$_ is a prefix of $test\n" for @found;
```

I also I imagine that there must be some way to use the smart-match operator `~~` to do this in a short-circuiting way. Also, as toolic points out the `List::Util` function could be used for this too. This stops the search after a match is found.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/first/;

my @prefixes = qw/ pre1 pre2 pre3 /;

my $test = 'pre1fixed';
my $found = first { $test =~ /^$_/ } @prefixes;

print "$found is the prefix of $test\n";
```

The only algorithm I am aware of is the [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) though I will leave it as an exercise to the reader (i.e. I don't know) to see if this will help you. I see that there is a module ([`Algorithm::AhoCorasick`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::AhoCorasick)). I also believe I have read somewhere that this and trie structures are implemented in Perl's matching under certain circumstances. Perhaps someone knows where I read that? Edit: found it in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909597/lengthy-perl-regex/4910594#4910594) on matching alternatives

Comment: `grep` will always search through the whole list, whereas `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils` functions can stop searching as soon as a match is found. This may be more efficient for large lists.

Comment: @toolic, I agree and just added such a comment to my answer, however the OP doesn't specifically ask for short-circuiting in his question.

Comment: You asked how `List::MoreUtils` was different from `grep`. So, I gave you one way in which they are different.

Answer (score 1):

The `first` function in the [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) Core module can find if a prefix matches a string. It searches through the list of prefixes, and returns as soon as it finds a match.  It does not search through the whole list if it is not necessary:

> first returns the first element where the
>   result from BLOCK is a true value. If
>   BLOCK never returns true or LIST was
>   empty then undef is returned.

Comment: Thanks, blanked on short-circuiting as I was looking. Voted you up then provided an example in my answer.