# check a given string match one of the prefixes in a file

Tags: perl, file-io, match, matching

Requirements: Given a file with a list of prefixes, one per line, check a given package name and return true if it matches one of the prefix. This is a subroutine of a project which involves a lot of packages. So efficiency is important. O(logn) or O(1) searching would be great.

I'm new to Perl. I did some search on this question and tried to follow [the answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134544/1131594). The only change I made is to read prefixes from a file. But it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use List::Util qw/first/;

sub isSkippedPackage {
  my $packageName = shift;
  my $found = first { $packageName =~ /^$_/ } @prefix;
  return (defined($found))
}   

my $file = qw(packageReplicationBlacklist.cfg);
open my $blacklist, '<', $file;
my @prefix = <$blacklist>;
print "prefix has: ", @prefix;
close $blacklist;

my $skipPackages = 1;
my $test = 'PackageA';
if ( $skipPackages && !isSkippedPackage($test) ) {
    print "No prefix for PackageA.\n" 
}
$test = 'PackageB';
if ( $skipPackages && isSkippedPackage($test) ) {
    print "Got a prefix for PackageB.\n" 
}
```

And in packageReplicationBlacklist.cfg file:

```
PackageB
PackageC
```

The current is:

```
prefix has: PackageB
PackageC
No prefix for PackageA.
```

It works if I use "my @prefix = qw/PackageB|PackageC/;". So, my guess is the file is read into an array but not a set of strings. How can I change it into a set of strings?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your program, and got the following errors:

```
Global symbol "@prefix" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$skipPackages" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$skipPackages" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 28.
```

However, that didn't surprise me because I knew I was going to get these errors. I'm surprised you didn't get them too.

You need to read up on Perl variable scoping which can be found in the [Perlsub tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) in Perldocs. Perl contains built in documentation via the [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) command. You can also see the same documentation in the [Perldoc webpage](http://perldoc.perl.org). Be careful that you have the correct version of Perl selected.

Basically, there are two types of variables in Perl: *Global* package variables and lexically scoped local variables.<sup>1</sup>

Package variables are defined using the `our $varable;` syntax. Lexically scoped *local* variables are defined with the `my $variable;` syntax.

In your case, you declare a `my @packages` variable inside your `if statement`. This is a variable that's only available in the if statement itself. Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# use strict;    #We don't want to use strict!
# use warnings;  #Not that either!

if (1 == 1) { #Always true
   my $foo = "Foo is defined";
   print "1. The value of foo is $foo\n";
}
print "2. The value of foo is $foo\n";
```

If we run this program we get:

```
1. The value of foo is Foo is defined
2. The value of foo is
```

That's because we lost the definition of `$foo` as we left the `if` statement.

An easy way to think of it is that curly braces denote blocks, and if a variable is declared as `my` inside the block, it is undefined outside the block.

Now, try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# use strict;    #We don't want to use strict!
# use warnings;  #Not that either!

if (1 == 1) { #Always true
   our $foo = "Foo is defined";  #Package Scoped
   print "1. The value of foo is $foo\n";
}
print "2. The value of foo is $foo\n";
```

Now, we run this program, we get:

```
1. The value of foo is Foo is defined
2. The value of foo is Foo is defined
```

That's because when we declare a variable with `our`, it's defined in the entire <strike>package</strike> *file*.<sup>2</sup>

In fact, if you think of the curly braces as defining *blocks*, you can think of a *my* variable declared in a block only being see in that block. You can even do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# use strict;    #We don't want to use strict!
# use warnings;  #Not that either!

{ #Creating a block...
   my $foo = "Foo is defined";
   print "1. The value of foo is $foo\n";
} #End of the block

print "2. The value of foo is $foo\n";
```

Again, you get:

```
1. The value of foo is Foo is defined
2. The value of foo is
```

That's because the curly braced denoted a block, and once you leave the block, the variable is no longer defined.

Now, try the last program and enable the `use strict;` and `use warnings;` statements. You should gets something like this:

```
Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name at ./test2.pl line 10.
```

That's because `use strict;` and `use warnings;` warn you of various types of errors. `use strict;` requires that you either declare a variable with either an `our` or `my`, and will warn you when variables go out of scope. The `use warnings;` pragma will give you oodles of warnings the most important is that you're using a variable without first giving it a value.

Let's redo that last program again:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $foo;
{
    $foo = "Foo is defined";
    print "1. The value of foo is $foo\n";
}

print "2. The value of foo is $foo\n";
```

This time, I declared `my $foo;` outside of the block, so it's lexically scoped in the entire program. Run this, and we get:

```
The value of foo is Foo is defined
The value of foo is Foo is defined
```

I'm sorry about the long winded explanation, but I hope that you understand the scoping of variables in Perl a bit better. If you declared `my @packages` and `my $skipPackages` at the beginning of your program, your program compiles. Except that it doesn't do what you want. Instead, you get the errors you had before.

I've rewritten your program a bit using more modern syntax:

- I'm using both `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. That's just good program practice.
- I've used the `use constant` to declare a constant for the file name. Syntax is a bit weird because constants don't have [sigils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) like Perl variables have. However, your file name is a constant. You don't want this to change in the middle of your program.
- I'm using `say` which is available since Perl 5.10. It's like `print`, but you don't have to keep using `\n` at the end of each line.
- You need to understand the difference between `qq(..)` which is like creating a word with double quotes and `qw(..)` which creates a *list*. You said  `my $file = qw(packageReplicationBlacklist.cfg);` which is syntactically incorrect. It worked in this case because Perl lists return a scalar of all the string values in this particular instance, so you lucked out. What you wanted to do is `my $file = qq(packageReplicationBlacklist.cfg);`. In fact, you probably really just wanted `q(packageReplacationBlacklist.cfg)` which are true single quotes. This way, your file doesn't cause problems if it started with an `@` or `$`. Take a look at the Perldoc for [Quote like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).
- I've eliminated the `List::Util` package because it's just more damn work than it's worth. I'll show you a rewritten subroutine that uses it later.
- Instead of `if (defined($blacklist)) {` statement to see if the file is opened or not, I am simply taking the return value of my `open` statement, and using `die` to kill my program if I can't open the file. You can also use the [autodie](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) to automatically kill bad file opens for you if you have Perl 5.10.1 or later.
- I pass all parameters I use in my subroutine to my subroutine. This way, I don't depend upon a global variable value. My subroutine uses all local variables.
- Finally, I'm using a `foreach` loop to loop though all the packages I want to test for. This way, I don't repeat code.

Now your program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    FILE_NAME => qq(packageReplicationBlackList.cfg),
};

my @prefix_list;
open my $black_list, "<", FILE_NAME
    or die qq(Couldn't open file ") . FILE_NAME . qq(" for reading: $!\n);

chomp ( @prefix_list = <$black_list> );
close $black_list;

foreach my $package_name  ( qw(PackageA PackageB) ) {
    if ( is_skipped_package( $package_name, @prefix_list ) ) {
        say qq(Package "$package_name" has a prefix);
    }
    else {
        say qq(No prefix found for "$package_name");
    }
}

sub is_skipped_package {
    my $package_name = shift;
    my @list         = @_;

    foreach my $package_to_test (@list) {
        if ( $package_name eq  $package_to_test ) {
            return $package_name;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
No prefix found for "PackageA"
Package "PackageB" has a prefix
```

Which is what you want.

Now, if you really want to use the first function of `List::Util`, you want to do this:

```
sub is_skipped_package {
    my $package_name = shift;
    my @list         = @_;

    use List::Util qw(first);

    return first { $_ eq $package_name }   @list;
}
```

I'm checking for equality and not a regular expression which is what I think you really wanted to do. Notice I am simply returning the value of the `first` function. If `first` finds a matching `$package_name`, it returns the package name, and therefore the results are defined, and my `if ( is_skipped_package( $package_name, @prefix_list ) ) {` statement will be true. If `$package_name` isn't found, the `first` function returns an undefined value, and my `if ( is_skipped_package( $package_name, @prefix_list ) ) {` statement will fail.

## Addendum

> One more question: this subroutine is part of a large project (and that's why I didn't use die since we don't want it die if there is no such file).

Fair enough. You could change the whole thing to a `if` statement: `if (open my $file, "<", $file) {`. This way, you're checking whether `open` worked and not whether `$file` is defined.

> If I want to store the prefixes in to a member field (like in Java), say $self->list. How to do it? Is it something like pkg = new packages(skipPackages => 1, list => @prefix_list); and in the new method, shall I use @{$self->list} or $self->@list? Thanks!

That's starting to get a bit complicated...

- You need to learn about [Perl packages](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) and how Perl namespace works.
- You need to learn about [Perl OOP programming](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) and how it works.
- You need to learn about [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). Notice in the subroutine, I pass in the whole array? Bad manners, but I didn't want to go into how to pass a reference to the array since you said you were new to Perl.
- You need a more secure foundation in Perl itself.

However, you asked, so here's a rough sample. This program would be called Local/Blacklist.pm. You'd use it by saying "use Local::BlackList":

```
package Local::BlackList;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return;
}

sub list {
    my $self =   shift;
    my $member = shift;

    if (not defined $self->{LIST}) {
        $self->{LIST} = [];
    }

    if (defined $member) {
       push @{$self->{LIST}}, $member;
    }

    return @{$self->{LIST}};
}

sub is_member {
   my $self = shift;
   my $item = shift;

   my @list = $self->list;
   foreach my $member (@list) {
      if ($member eq $item) {
          return $item;
      }
   }
   return;
}
```

I've defined a class called Local::BlackLlist that will contain your list. It's a rather simple class. No way to delete members from the list. This class contains two methods: One adds fields to the list and returns the list. The other sees if a member is a member of the list.

To create a new class object, you'd do this:

```
  my $blacklist = Local::BlackList->new;
```

To add a prefix to the list, you'd do this:

```
  $blacklist->list( $prefix );
```

To retrieve the list, you'd do this:

```
  my @prefix_list = $blacklist->list;
```

To check whether or not something is a member of the list, you'd do this:

```
 if ( $blacklist->is_member( $member ) )  {
    say qq(Item "$member" is a member of the list);
 }
 else {
    say qq(Item "$member" is not a member of the list);
 }
```

Note that there are three subroutines. The `new` is my *constructor*. Note that there's nothing special about the keyword *new*. It's sort of a standard that has developed over the years. All my `new` subroutine did was create a reference to an anonymous hash. The *object* I create is simply a reference to this hash.

Note in my `list` subroutine, I check to see if the key to the hash, *LIST*, exists or not. If it doesn't exist, I create a hash key "LIST" which simply points to an anonymous array. In my list subroutine, I *dereference* this reference to the array like this `@{$self->{LIST}}`. I can push stuff on to the array *dereferenced* this way, and I can return the array itself. I could have returned a reference to the array if I felt that the array could get really, really big and be a memory hog:

```
sub list {
    my $self =   shift;
    my $member = shift;

    if (not defined $self->{LIST}) {
        $self->{LIST} = [];
    }

    if (defined $member) {
       push @{$self->{LIST}}, $member;
    }

    return $self->{LIST};
}
```

Now, I'd have to do this:

```
my $list_ref = $blacklist->list;
my @list = @{$list_ref};
```

to turn the returned reference back into an array. By the way, I don't like this because it allows people to directly manipulate the array:

```
   $list_ref = @blacklist->list;

   $value= pop @{$list_ref};
```

That actually changed my class object! I want to be very careful handing people references back to structure of my class because people might do something without realizing it.

This is just a taste how object oriented Perl is written. Learn the basics, before you start getting too involved with references and more complex data structures.

---

<sup>1.</sup> I lied, there are now also *state* variables that are new to Perl 5.12, and the dreaded *local* variable which isn't really a local variable, but a global package variable that is part of the cruft that Perl has developed over the last two decades.

In 99% of the cases, if you declare a variable using `local $variable`, you are probably doing it wrong. You know how Adam and Jamie before every Mythbuster show say "Don't try this at home. We're professionals?" That's the `local` declaration. Don't use `local` unless you're a top flight Perl developer and love living in a world where things can blow up in your face.

<sup>2.</sup> A package is declared with the `package` statement. Once used, all Perl package variables and functions are in that package. Packages are mainly used in Perl modules to prevent name collisions when defining subroutines and non-lexically scoped variables. See the [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) function for more information.

In your case, everything is just part of the `main` package which means it's available in the entire file,

Comment: Thank you, David, for the very detailed explain! I already noticed that I made a mistake by declaring a local variable but using it outside the block. So, I've edited the original post. :D

Comment: Oh, I didn't know hitting enter will post the comment... Anyway. One more question: this subroutine is part of a large project (and that's why I didn't use die since we don't want it die if there is no such file). If I want to store the prefixes in to a member field (like in Java), say $self->list. How to do it?    Is it something like `pkg = new packages(skipPackages => 1, list => @prefix_list);` and in the new method, shall I use `@{$self->list}` or `$self->@list`? Thanks!

Comment: @arosima See the addendum to my answer. It is possible in Perl to do that. In fact, that's what Perl 5 was all about -- object orientedness. However, it's probably more complex than you want to handle for now.

Comment: Thanks, @David-w! I still got a little bit confused. I can understand that `$blacklist->list( $prefix );` is calling the subroutine `list`. But when retrieving the list, you use `my @prefix_list = $blacklist->list;'. Is the `list` here the subroutine or the member field? Suppose I have a subroutine read prefixes from a file and initialize the member field, and then when I use the member field, I hope it would not read the file again and again.

Comment: @arosima `my @prefix_list = $blacklist->list;` is calling the subroutine `list`. It just happens that `list` returns the array. Member variables can be package variables (declared with `our`), or just a method that sets/gets the value. I usually prefer the latter. [State variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) can also be used in classes. State variables were introduced in Perl 5.10.